# htaccess: redirect to url without variable

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect users to a URL without a specific variable. For example

```
example.com/?hop=hahaha
```

I would like to remove the hop variable and redirect to

```
example.com/
```

This for subdirectories as well for example

```
example.com/subdir/?hop=hahaha
```

or

```
example.com/subdir?hop=hahaha
```

becomes

```
example.com/subdir
```

I have this so far but it only works for root domains, not subdirs

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^hop=
RewriteRule .* /? [R,L]
```

(For reference *Clickbank* adds the hop variables to landing pages)

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^hop=
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks just tried it but it redirects from `http://mysite.com/?hop=hahaha` to `http://mysite.com/home/mysite/public_html`
It outputs the linux path :)

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: I am using Drupal, so in Drupal's htaccess after `# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on`

Comment: Can you add it to a Virtual Host section?

Comment: I am on a shared host, so no access to that.

Comment: If so, insert a leading slash in substitution: `RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R,L]` and try again.

Comment: Yep, almost there. The only issue is that now it redirects to root from a subdirectory, so `mysite.com/subdir/?hop=hahaha` now goes to `mysite.com`, how could the subdirectory be preserved so that it redirects to `mysite.com/subdir`?

Comment: It sounds like you put the `.htaccess` file into `subdir`, move it to the document root and try again.

Comment: .htacess is located in root, at mysite.com/.htaccess

Comment: Please post the full config.

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess

Comment: Haven't you added the above config? I tested on my laptop and it works fine.

Comment: I just tested it on xampp, but there as well it redirects to root from me, from a subdirectory. I would like to preserve the subdirectory, but without the variable.